# How can I publish my winform application with SQL Express installation and configuration?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my first time publishing my application. I am using Visual Studio 2015 and it doesn't appear to have a setup project. Maybe my installation was not complete? Is there a norm in publishing Winform applications? Or would I need to create a form for an installation wizard. Also, my installation needs to include and configure SQL Express like attaching my empty mdfs, assigning an sa login and such.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use ClickOnce publishing.

In properties of your project, in publish tab, click prerequisites button, you can select SQL Express in prerequisites. This way, you only need to set your database files to copy in output directory, and use AttachDbFileName in connection string.

Also you can create a LocalDB bootstrapper and use LocalDB too. To read more about how to include LocalDb in ClickOnce prerequisites you can take a look at this [technet thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/551ca300-6188-46e0-9fd9-07ca6ec1daf1/sql-server-2014-clickonce-bootstrapper-package-availability?forum=winformssetup).

Comment: I see, If I got this right, I would need to put my mdfs in my projects folder first?

Comment: Yes, you can copy your sql express database files in output directory, using properties of those files in solution explorer. Also you can copy it anywhere else. you can take a look at [Accessing Local and Remote Data in ClockOnce Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8saf4wy.aspx)

Comment: What about  my current connection string that is in my app.config? What if during the installation of sql express the user setup a different password? Do I need to do something about my sql password in the app.config before publishing?

Comment: @JoshuaMasangcay This way, you should `AttachDBFileName` in your connection string. You can use it in your app config, or set it in code.

Comment: @JoshuaMasangcay using `AttachDBFileName` in connection string you  point to the full path of your mdf file to be attached to SQL Express.