# Visual Studio project mdf

Tags: c#, sql-server, localdb

I have a project that needs a local cache of certain items in a remote db. I decided to add a local database (`.mdf` file) to the project that caches this data (that doesn't change at all or at least very very infrequently)

The reason for this is there are about 100 users accessing the remote database and one important table has about 2 million rows and about 50 columns of data (I know it is poorly designed but I didn't design it). There are a few queries that get run that are hard on the database, such as text compare using the like `'%%'` command.

These are run on the columns that I want to be in the local cache so I can move performance hits from the remote to the local db (as to not affect everybody but just the user doing the search).

Now on to the issue. All the developer PCs run it just fine. All the end users PCs however throw an error that they cannot connect.

Searching shows they need SQL Server Express (even though I don't have SQL Server Express and it works on my machine). However all I find reference to SQL Server 2012 Express.

I had one user install SQL Server 2017 Express LocalDB from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express but it still didn't fix the issue.

Please point me to what is needed on the end users machines to get this to work.   Also please don't suggest sqlite as I already tried it and it was too slow for the work needed. I am open to other solutions

Comment: I think SQL express is installed automatically along with visual studio, which is why you have it while the users don't.

Comment: @TJWolschon SQL Server Express is a totally separate product to Visual Studio. You can have one without the other.

Comment: @Larnu I'm aware of that, but I believe it's included in one of the packages in the visual studio installer

Comment: @TJWolschon yeah i thought of that but I can not find it running even in my services menu.  I do have sql management studios and think that may have installed something to cause this to work but what im after is what do the end users need installed for this to work as i had one user install SQL Server 2017 Express LocalDB as stated above and they still got the same connection error.  All searches to the issue only reference SQL Express 2012 which is old and I'm looking for a up to date solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deploy application with sql server database on clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956142/how-to-deploy-application-with-sql-server-database-on-clients)