# How publish vb.net project with local database

Tags: database, vb.net

I use visual studio 2015
,I create project with service based database when i published my project as exe and install on my computer it running but when install on other computer give error
[image: error :50]

other computer give this error [image: error]

i installed localDB on other computers but error is same --
my connection string `connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DBUBMP.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`

Comment: Is SQL Server Express installed on the target computer?

Comment: yes , i installed SQL server on target computer .

Comment: Do you have a LocalDB\MSSQLLocalDB instance on the machine. `C:\Users\[User Name]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB` ? And is your `DBUBMP.mdf` there?

Comment: DBUBMP.mdf not found

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed sql Management server is installed, start it up and look if the local database user/pwd are in order.
you can there see also which name  the database engine answers.

you should also look at the configuration manager if tcp ip is activated.

you can see how you can deplay databases with your app [How to deploy application with sql server database on clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956142/how-to-deploy-application-with-sql-server-database-on-clients?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before and I got it fixed by adding the LocalDB feature while I installed SQL Server from the end of the setup wizard. Look for customize and make sure localDB is ticked.