# How to put a SQL Server database on a DVD

Tags: sql-server, database

I've tried posting my question in a search engine, but can't get any relevant information. And I'm not really sure how to ask the question simply. So here it goes.

I've got some software that makes use of a SQL Server database. However, I need to make this data accessible on a DVD disk. How do I put the loaded SQL Server database onto the disk? I'm using SQL Server Express or SQL Server (I need to check licensing).

I suspect that my steps will be:

1. Create and load the database with the necessary data.
2. Create an idb file to reference the disk database.
3. Copy the files to the disk using a burner application.
4. ...
5. Profit!

It's step 3 I'm unsure about - which files?

Comment: #3 has nothing to do with programming. You can even drag&drop files to the DVD icon and the OS will. write them. What you should be concerned with is how to use a database when it's impossible to write to a log file. `ldb` is the log file, not the data file

Comment: I'm reasonably certain SQL Server won't like the transaction log being read only - so you'll probably need to plan to copy the database files off of the disk before it's usable.

Comment: Another concern is the actual edition. SQL Server isn't free, SQL Server Express is. Even that will run as a server application though. To treat databases. as files you need to use [Sql Server's LocalDB feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deploy application with sql server database on clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956142/how-to-deploy-application-with-sql-server-database-on-clients)