# vb.net setup not installing prequisites

Tags: vb.net, winforms, setup-project

I created a project that has a pre requisite of SQL Server 2019 Express LocalDB and Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2, but the thing is when i install it to new pc (VirtualBox) it didn't install any of the Pre req1uisite included, i have checked the installed programs on control panel but it it's not installed. I followed this article in this community : [Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956142/how-to-deploy-application-with-sql-server-database-on-clients)

what should I do? any hints, i've been stucked in this process this whole week. can some body point it out at least?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the SQL Server 2019 Express from the URL:https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=101064
as the SQL Express instance needs to be installed on the client machine so as to run the SQL database.

Comment: okay, so how am i going to install the sql server using the file setup that i have created? can you at least teach me how